# JConfirm on Link

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jconfirm

Hi I have an anchor that I am trying to get a JConfirm box to work with, But Its just popping up and disappearing. There is an image in the anchor with an "X"

```
onclick='jConfirm("Do you really want to do that?.\n ","Import",
    e.preventDefault(); 
    if(!ans) {                                                      
    return false;
     }
});'>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this (untested)... think about what is `ans` in your code?

```
jConfirm('Do you really want to do that?', 'Import', function(ans) {
    if(!ans) {                                                      
    return false;
     }
  });
```

Also it is always cleaner to do this using `delegate` or `on` rather than doing inline...

Comment: Sorry, Thats more or less what I have. Didn't paste it correctly. I copied exactly what you have, but the Confirmation Box pops up and instantly goes away.

Answer (score 0):

This works

```
$('.deleteconfirm').click(function(e)
                                {
                                link = this;
                                url=link.getAttribute('href')
                                e.preventDefault();
                                jConfirm(("Delete this Report Association?"),'Report',function(confirmed)
                                {
                                    if(confirmed)
                                        {
                                        window.location =url;                                   
                                        }
                                })
                                            });
```